# Retrieving Mysql data and print in specific order

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I got a problem that driving me crazy for last 4 or 5 days.I'm building a facebook style posting system,where users can post on their timeline and friends of that user can comment on every specific post.I'm actually having problem to print that correctly in php.Your help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

The 'status' table that I created for all the post contain following values

```
id   osid   author  type  data    postdate
1     1     helal    a    Hi...  2014-08-20 
2     1     Abdul    b    Hey..  2014-08-20
3     1     helal    b    Good..     "
4     4     helal    a    Hello..    "
5     4     Irin     b    Hi...      "
```

so,basically,all new posts are having type 'a' and all replies are having type 'b'.And also,all separate conversation(post and replies) is having same 'osid',so that user can see separate conversation on separate div with a comment box attached to each post(followed by conversation)

I coded the following code,but it's not giving me expected result.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM status WHERE type='a'";
$query=mysqli_query($connect_dude,$sql);
$numrow=mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($numrow>0){

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  $id=$row["id"];
  $osid=$row["osid"];
  $name=$row["author"];
  $data=$row["data"];
  $date=$row["postdate"];

    $query_replies = mysqli_query($connect_dude, "SELECT * FROM status WHERE type='b' AND osid='$id' ");

    $replynumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query_replies);
     if($replynumrows > 0){
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_replies) ) {
        $statusreplyid = $row2["id"];
        $statusreplyosid = $row2["osid"];
        $replyauthor = $row2["author"];
        $replydata = $row2["data"];
        $replydata = nl2br($replydata);
        $replypostdate = $row2["postdate"];
        $replydata = str_replace("&amp;","&",$replydata);
        $replydata = stripslashes($replydata);




        $status_replies .= '<div id="reply_'.$statusreplyid.'" class="reply_boxes"><div><b>Reply by <a href="user.php?u='.$replyauthor.'">'.$replyauthor.'</a> '.$replypostdate.':</b><br />'.$replydata.'</div></div>';


           }
         }



    $statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$id.'" class="status_boxes"><div><b>Posted by <a href="user.php?u='.$name.'">'.$name.'</a> '.$date.':</b> '.$statusDeleteButton.' <br />'.$data.'</div>'.$status_replies.'</div>';



    if($logged == $username){
    $statuslist .= '<form id="posting1" action="user.php?u='.$logged.'" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><textarea id="replytext" name="replytext" class="replytext" placeholder="write a comment here '.$osid.'"></textarea><input id="hel1" name="hel1" type="hidden" value="'.$osid.'"><input type="submit" id="replyBtn" name="replyBtn" value="reply"></form>'; 
      }

    }


$postbox="<form id='posting' action='user.php?u=$logged' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'><input id='hid' name='hid' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $iid;?>' ><textarea id='taxi' name='taxi' rows='15' cols='40' placeholder='Say something to your Buddies'></textarea></br><input id='hel' name='hel' type='submit' value='post'></form>";
 }
}
```

and I have used echoed '$statuslist' on html part.

It keeps compounding all replies within all the post.

Desired form of result,let say

```
    For post no 1      
    helal:Hi...
    Abdul:hello...
    helal:Good....
    "then the comment box(reply text area)"

    For post no 2      
    helal:Hello...
    Irin:Hi...
    "then the comment box(reply text area)"
```

so on and so forth within separate divs for separate conversation

Comment: can you post your desired result?

Comment: Hi,Question is updated.Please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you need to reset `$status_replies` in the outer loop. Add:

```
$status_replies = '';
```

anywhere between the two `while` lines.

Comment: wow,it worked.Thanks a loooooooooooooooooooooooooooot.I appreciate your help.